# How to insert a jint into a jobjectArray?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How can I properly construct and pass an array of diverse objects through jni? I seem to have trouble converting a jint into jobject.
My original function was:

```
extern "C"  JNIEXPORT jint ... Func(...)
{
    int res = CallNativeFunc();
    return res;
}
```

Now, I am modifying the function so it will return an array of objects. The first object will be the original `res`, and the second object will be a jbyteArray.

I have tried:

```
extern "C"  JNIEXPORT jobjectArray ... Func(...)
{
   std::vector<unsigned char> outData;
   int res = CallNativeFunc(&outData);

   //construct the returning object array of size 2
   jclass objectClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Object");
   jobjectArray results = env->NewObjectArray(2, objectClass, 0);

   //construct the 2nd object (a jbyteArray)
   jbyteArray SecondObject = env->NewByteArray(outData.size());
   //transfer data into the 2nd object
   env->SetByteArrayRegion(SecondObject , 0, outData.size(), reinterpret_cast<const signed char*>(outData.data()));

   //transfer the 1st and 2nd objects into the return array
   env->SetObjectArrayElement(results, 0, static_cast<jint>(res));
   env->SetObjectArrayElement(results, 1, SecondObject);

   return results;
}
```

The compiler fails at the following line, saying it cannot convert a jint into jobject:

```
env->SetObjectArrayElement(results, 0, static_cast<jint>(res));
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct approach to do what I am trying to do? (pass an array "structure" of sorts back to the java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` in Java is a primitive type, not an `Object`. So if you want to store an `int` in an `Object[]` you need to wrap it in an `Integer`.

The code would look something like this (untested):

```
jclass integerClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID integerConstructor = env->GetMethodID(integerClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject wrappedInt = env->NewObject(integerClass, integerConstructor, static_cast<jint>(res));
env->SetObjectArrayElement(results, 0, wrappedInt);
```